# How can I get the latest N posts from blogger RSS feed?

Tags: browser, javascript, rss, blogging, feed-reader

How can I get the latest N posts from blogger RSS feed, using the URL in a browser, or some javascript? Which parameter do I have to use?

Comment: Using what... ? An RSS reader (which one?), from a programming language, from a browser.....

Comment: From a browser, using the url. Or from javascript.

Comment: Maybe this is a workaround: you can use FeedBurner to create a HTML/Javascript widget which you then insert at Blogger, and then you'd call that.

http://www.helperblogger.com/2012/03/feedburner-recent-posts-widget-for.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Developers Guide: Protocol for Google's Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#RetrievingWithQuery), the query parameter to be used is **max-results**, like this:

```
http://www.blogger.com/feeds/blogID/posts/default?max-results=N
```

Where **blogID** is the blog ID number, and **N** is the number of posts to retrieve. The posts are ordered by last modified by default.

Comment: this works for blogspot domains too:
 https://YOURBLOG.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=N